# How to use Streamreader data in another method in C# using windows form app

Tags: c#, methods, readfile, streamreader, openfiledialog

I'm new to using C# in windows form application and I'm trying to get data from an opened file that was read in the streamreader in one method and use it in another method.

The method streamreader was initially used in:

```
private void mnuFileLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //open file and store values into array 
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            //reading the file selected
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //reads first line in file (size of array)
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileDialog.OpenFile());
                int data = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

            }
        }
```

Trying to transfer the streamreader data to another method and use its data

```
private void btnAscending_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//reads first line in file (size of array)
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(what do I put here);
            int data = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
}
```

How can I use its data in the method that it was initially used without using the OpenFileDialog command again in another method?

Comment: You could move "int data" up one level(scope) and that way it would be accessible to both methods. Or you could call other methods with your click methods. One of the methods could then pass the data to the other.

Comment: Move the whole _mnuFileLoad_Click_ code to its own method and make that method return the integer value read. Then you can call it from everywhere in your class

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below. Your existing methods are within a class. To give you an example, I put my methods in the class `MyClass`. Your class will have a different name. But see the line `StreamReader sr = null;` Since that declaration is on class level the variable sr can be accessed by any non static method in the class now. To make that clear, I used this.sr one time. But the this-keyword isn't required as you can see in the other method below.

I also added a null check to make sure that the file was opened before, otherwise you're getting an error.

I also added a couple of comments to guide you further

```
class MyClass
{
    StreamReader sr = null;
    
    private void mnuFileLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //open file and store values into array 
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        //reading the file selected
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //reads first line in file (size of array)
            this.sr = new StreamReader(fileDialog.OpenFile());
            int data = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

        }
    }

    private void btnAscending_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //reads first line in file (size of array)
        // sr = new StreamReader(what do I put here); No longer required
        
        if (sr == null)
        {
            // When the file wasn't opened yet, sr will be null, in this case do nothing
            return;
        }
        
        // now continue using sr as planned
        int data = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what the logic is about and where your goal is. This is not clearly recognisable from your question.

In your example, you create the StreamReader again with the comment that the first line should be read out again. So both methods should always read out the first line of the file, correct?

If so, then I would not work with a stream, but remember the file path:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the last selected file from the OpenFileDialog.
        /// </summary>
        private string LastSelectedFile { get; set; } = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads the first line from the given file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file">The full path to the file.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the parsed content of the first line.</returns>
        protected int ReadFromFile(string file)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                return int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        private void BtnFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.LastSelectedFile = fileDialog.FileName;
                int data = this.ReadFromFile(this.LastSelectedFile);
            }
        }

        private void BtnSecondButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int data = this.ReadFromFile(this.LastSelectedFile);
        }
```

However, if the content of the file does not change, then I would rather remember the value read out in a property instead of the last file opened:

```cs
        private int FileContent { get; set; }

        private void BtnFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileDialog.OpenFile()))
                {
                    this.FileContent = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }

        private void BtnSecondButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int data = this.FileContent;
        }
```

If different contents are to be read from the file, then the answer from AdrAs would be more suitable for you.